# What are the uses of Null handler in python logging?

Tags: python, logging

According to python's documentation,

> The NullHandler class, located in the core logging package, does not
>   do any formatting or output. It is essentially a ‘no-op’ handler for
>   use by library developers.

If it doesn't print to anything, what is the use of this handler at all? Why would one go to lengths to write loggers and then use null handler to not print anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you can keep your `logger.warning('Whatever')` statements in your code, but conditionally inject a logger that entirely disregards them if you don't want a log in certain situations.

Comment: I kind of understand what you said. But, not really clear. Is it possible to show this with an example? that would be great

Comment: Well, you intersperse logging statements like `logger.info(...)` throughout your code wherever you think it might be useful to produce logs, right? Now in some situations you might not want to produce any logs for whatever reasons. Instead of removing all those lines, you simply set a logger which does nothing (either through dependency injection or by setting a default logger or whatever).

Comment: That's Awesome. So, if i do want library's logs, what should i do? since, its already been using null handler, if i want to save these logs of the library to the file, what should i change?

Comment: Depends on the specific library…? There may be some flag you're supposed to set, or parameter to pass, or logger instance to pass, or perhaps you just need to set the default handler in the global `logging` module.

Comment: can i just add file or stream handler by doing this ?
 -> logging.getLogger(library_name).addhandler

Comment: I'm not too sure about the specifics, post a new questions with details if you need those.

Comment: I'm don't think this answer is on target.  The question is about a Handler, yet the answer talks about injecting a Logger - which is not something that is easy (and possibly not sensible) to do.

Answer (score 5):

The real benefit of the NullHandler is as a way to avoid the "handler of last resort".

This comes into play when a log-entry has been sent to a logger, but neither it nor any of its parents have an explicit handler attached.  In such circumstances, Python's logging library has a `lastResort` handle that (by default) will route to a `stderr` stream handler set at warning level.

*One* way of preventing this is to attach a NullHandler in one the the loggers in the hierarchy, and this will prevent the `lastResort` from kicking in.

When thinking about logging, one has to consider propagation, handlers at each level, and default behaviours at the end of traversing the logger hierarchy.